# Bash and git subshell extra output

Tags: bash, git

I have this simple git command

```
$ git branch | grep nathan-terraform-test-2 | head -1
* nathan-terraform-test-2
```

I want to wrap this up in a command substitution

```
TEST=$(git branch | grep nathan-terraform-test-2 | head -1)
```

The problem comes when I echo the variable

```
$ echo $TEST
README.md commit-list.py dev-apps environments global-apps qa-apps staging-apps nathan-terraform-test-2
```

The output is the branch I was doing a grep on and it looks like its doing an 'ls' on the current directory I'm in. Why am I getting this extra output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I getting this extra output?

Because filename expansion  is run over unquoted results of other expansions.  To prevent filename expansion (and word splitting)  quite the expansion.  As a general rule,  if you write `$` it should be inside `"`.

```
echo "$test"
```